# Centering two elements in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, centering

I have two TextView elements, with changing length. How do I get them to be centered horizontally in an RelativeLayout? The RelativeLayout must wrap_content, as I have views to the left of it.
See my sketch below:
[image: Adjust width according to contents.]

It doesn't have to be a RelativeLayout, as long I can position the two TextViews above each other.

EDIT:
Based on the answers I tried this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/centerContainer"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:text="Mmmmmmmmmmmm"
        android:id="@+id/upperText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="M"
        android:id="@+id/lowerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/upperText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edited. Now it is formulated as a question.

Comment: First anchor the blue View to the parent's right and then center the two TextViews horizontally in the parent, setting the second one below the first one

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />
```

thats it...

> android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" -> if true, center this child
>   horizontally within its parent

Answer (score 0):

You must have something like :

```
<RelativeLayout
    some options...
   <TextView 
      some options...
   />
   <TextView
      some options...
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add `android:gravity = "center"` to your `RelativeLayout` options :

```
<RelativeLayout
    some options...
    android:gravity = "center"
   <TextView 
      some options...
   />
   <TextView
      some options...
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should center every element in your `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: `center_horizontal` in his/her case.